# Simplification of a series (power series without an x?)

Tags: sequences-and-series

If it is possible, how can I simplify $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n 10^{n}$

Comment: I wouldn't say simplification is really possible, without having some constraints on $a_n$.  Interestingly if you add the requirements that 1. $a_n$ is always an integer from 0 to 9, and only a finite number of $n$ values have a non-zero value for $a_n$, this formula describes **the natural numbers**, in a way that's useful for describing digit-based algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a closed formula $g(x)$ for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ and the condition $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty} \lvert a_k\rvert^{1/k}<\dfrac1{10}$ holds, then you can write that quantity as $g(10)$.